# Java Mouse Robot Issue only on Mac?

Tags: java, macos, mouse

Recently I designed a clickbot for a client, and it worked fine on my windows computer. The program clicks the mouse at a very high click / second rate. When run on a Mac, the mouse glitched out. Here is a video highlighting the issue:  https://vid.me/4nkuj

Here is the clicker class:

```
public void run() {
    try {
    LeftClicker mouse = new LeftClicker();
    System.out.println("****Clicker Initated****");
    System.out.println("Randomization: " +randomization );
    System.out.println("Clicks / Second: " +clickCount );
    while (!shouldStop && clickCount > 0)
    {
        Long time = System.nanoTime();
        double[] seconds = Algorithms.genStructure(randomization, clickCount);


        for (int i=0; i<seconds.length;i++)
        {
            new Thread(mouse).start();
        Thread.sleep((long) (seconds[i]));
        }

        System.out.println("Time: " + (System.nanoTime() - time));

}
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Each part of the code works perfectly and yields no errors. To my knwoledge, no error is thrown on the mac. I really am clueless. The mac is running Java 8.

Here is the left clicker class:

```
private Robot controller;

public LeftClicker()
{
    try {
        controller=new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
public void run() {
    controller.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(4);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    controller.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
}
```

The way the code is designed it should be impossible to run more than 1 leftclicker at any given moment.

Comment: Why do you need to start a new `Thread` on each cycle of the loop?

Comment: Just for better performance- don't want to have to wait for the click to occur for however many milliseconds the operating system takes. The program has a set amount of seconds it must wait before continuing.

Comment: So, you're going to pick a fight with the OS then?  This seems, to me, to be the focus of the issue - yes I "know" it works on Windows, but Windows allows you to do some crazy stuff some times - IMHO

Comment: Would rewriting it in .NET help or would it yield the same results?

Comment: I doubt it, but you could try. I think issue comes more down to you spamming the mouse clicks and the OS trying to mange the state, but I'm only guessing